# Why do I keep getting undefined here?

Tags: javascript

total_1 keeps bringing back undefined. What am I doing wrong? I want to add 10 to the total if the divisors of total are greater than it, if not I want to only add 5. The others come up fine it is only total_1 that comes up undefined.

```
function findMark (){
     var x1 = document.getElementById("fn").value;
     var x2 = document.getElementById("ln").value;
     var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("midterm").value*0.35);
     var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("assign").value*0.1);
     var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("quiz").value*0.15);
     var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("final").value*0.4);
     var total = Math.round(grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4);
     var total_1 = findFinalMark(total);
     document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "Name = " + x1 + " " + x2 + "<br>" + "Your mark is = " + total + "%" + "<br>" + "Your Final Mark = " + total_1 + "%";

     function findFinalMark (x) {
     sum = 0;
     i = 1;
     while (i < x){
        if (x % i == 0){
            sum += i;
        }
        i++;
     }
     if (sum > x) {
        x = x + 10;
     }
     else {
        x = x + 5;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your `midterm`, `assign`, `quiz`, and `final` inputs have `type=text` trying to perform math operations on their value won't give you an integer. Set them to `type="number"` or use `parseInt`.

Comment: i am using type="number" on them. The only one that gives me undefined is total_1. I know the problem is from my js and not html.

Comment: your `findFinalMark` function is not returning a value

Comment: Well... `findFinalMark` doesn't return anything.

Comment: so like this? 
   if (sum > x) {
   return x = x + 10;
   }
   else {
   return x = x + 5;
   }

Comment: Just add a `return x` statement at the end.

Comment: Do not add solved to the question, that is what accepting an answer is for.  [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry!! Second question only I will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

You do not return anything from the function so it is undefined.

So you need to return `x` or `sum` from the function. Also use `var` when declaring variables so you do not flood the global namespace.

```
function findFinalMark (x) {
    var sum = 0,
        i = 1;
    /* your logic */
    return x; //or sum or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: you mean make var sum and var i?

Comment: Yes, that is how you declare variables.

Answer (score 0):

should your function findFinalMark return sum?

Comment: no it should what i put in my if and else statements. should i be doing something this?
   if (sum > x) {
   return x = x + 10;
   }
   else {
   return x = x + 5;
   }